# JavaScript - Split A String

Tags: javascript, split, substring

I have a variable that holds the value 'website.html'.

How can I split that variable so it only gives me the 'website'?

Thanks

Comment: @Jack This page was the first hit when I Googled "javascript split string dot". Saying "Google it" helps no one.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var a = "website.html";
var name = a.split(".")[0];
```

If the file name has a dot in the name, you could try...

```
var a = "website.old.html";
var nameSplit = a.split(".");
nameSplit.pop();    
var name = nameSplit.join(".");
```

But if the file name is something like `my.old.file.tar.gz`, then it will think `my.old.file.tar` is the file name

Comment: This does not work, if the filename has a dot in its name like: my.super.website.html.

Comment: var nameSplit = a.split(".");
nameSplit.pop();    
var name = nameSplit.join(".");

Make `nameSplit.join(".")` instead of `name.join(".")` , It will work.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] splitString = "website.html".split(".");
String prefix = splitString[0];
```

*Edit, I could've sworn you put Java not javascript

```
var splitString = "website.html".split(".");
var prefix = splitString[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing things using some [String manipulation](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/string3.shtml).

```
var myString = "website.html";
var dotPosition = myString.indexOf(".");
var theBitBeforeTheDot = myString.substring(0, dotPosition);
```

Comment: +1 This requires more code, but don't requires aditional comments to understand.

Comment: I remember learning basic string manipulation before the quicker 'Array.split' method clicked with me (:

Comment: It's worth noting that some older browsers do not support `.indexOf()`

Comment: @JonnyReeves Whoops, yes, you're right - I was thinking about `[].indexOf`